# Using foreach in conjunction with a multi-dimensional array(?)

Tags: php

I am trying to use Simple HTML DOM to cycle through an HTML file and find all HREF links that contain the string "/en/news/". For each of these values in this initial array, I want to give certain attributes as seen below.

```
foreach($html->find('a[href^="/en/news/"]') as &$a) {
    $arrayz = array(
        'hyperLink' => 'http://samplewebsite.com' . $a->href,
        'fileName' => str_replace("-", "", filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) . ".txt",
        'processedTime' => date_default_timezone_get()
    );
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($arrayz), '</pre>';
```

However, this is only printing the hyperLink, filename, and processedTime values for a SINGLE member of the initial array.

How can I make this work for all members of the initial array?

Thanks!

Comment: `print_r()` is your friend to help figure out structure of your input array. For multi-dimensional arrays you may need nested `foreach`s

Comment: I recommend jQuery/JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting a single array inside the loop, try this:

```
foreach($html->find('a[href^="/en/news/"]') as &$a) {
    $arrayz[] = array(
        'hyperLink' => 'http://samplewebsite.com' . $a->href,
        'fileName' => str_replace("-", "", filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) . ".txt",
        'processedTime' => date_default_timezone_get()
    );

}

echo '<pre>', print_r($arrayz), '</pre>';
```